# Save TextInput on button press - kivy/python

Tags: python, kivy

I have a class with a button "Save game", which opens a popup with textinput widget and a button with which I would like to save the users text input. I tried this but it doesn't work. 
If I print out the filename after "modifying" it, it prints out the filename that I defined beforehand: .txt, not Game1.txt or something like this.

```
class Something(Widget):
    filename = ".txt"
    # code for game
    def save(self,*args):
        def on_text(instance, value):
            return value

        name = TextInput(text="")
        name.bind(text=on_text)
        self.filename = "{}.txt".format(name.text)

        b = BoxLayout()
        save_button = Button(text="Save file")
        b.add_widget(save_button)
        b.add_widget(name)
        popup = Popup(title="Enter the name:", content=b)

        save_button.bind(on_release=popup.dismiss)
        name.bind(on_text_validate=popup.on_dismiss) # I wanted to save it when the user closes the popup
        popup.open()
```

Where am I doing it wrong? (I know this won't actually save it, I just want to create the name here, I have a different class method for saving it)

Comment: It looks like you don't even touch filename after you've created the popup, how is it suppose to set it?

Comment: That is why I posted this question because I don't understand how this should be done.

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking at a similar problem: when the user types text into a text input box, *but does not hit return before hitting the 'exit' button*, the changes are lost.

You might want to see if this is your error as well.